# Why BoundedDiagram fails?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a set of points:

```
pts={{2.28571, 2.79821}, {2.28571, 3.79821}, {2.28571, 4.79821}, {3.57143,
   1.1375}, {3.57143, 2.1375}, {3.57143, 3.1375}, {3.57143, 
  4.1375}, {4.85714, 0.316071}, {4.85714, 1.31607}, {4.85714, 
  2.31607}, {4.85714, 3.31607}, {4.85714, 4.31607}, {6.14286, 
  0.316071}, {6.14286, 1.31607}, {6.14286, 2.31607}, {6.14286, 
  3.31607}, {6.14286, 4.31607}, {7.42857, 1.1375}, {7.42857, 
  2.1375}, {7.42857, 3.1375}, {7.42857, 4.1375}, {8.71429, 
  2.79821}, {8.71429, 3.79821}, {8.71429, 4.79821}}
```

And I am trying to make its Bounded Voronoi Diagram. When using DiagramPlot I get proper result:
[image]

But when using BoundedDiagram with bound: `{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 6}, {0, 6}}` following error occurs:

```
RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix {{-10.,0.,600.},{-7.99361\[CenterDot]10^-15,3.12639\[CenterDot]10^-13,-1.60087\[CenterDot]10^-12}} may contain significant numerical errors. >>
```

And actually description of this error hardly suggests why this occurs. How to workaround this?

EDIT: when points are moved randomly just a bit in random direction function doesn't fail.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work despite the warning message:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
{diagvert1, diagval1} = 
    BoundedDiagram[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 6}, {0, 6}}, pts];
DiagramPlot[pts, diagvert1, diagval1]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I re-pasted the point coordinates. Maybe by accident I pasted those working (moved a bit randomly). Anyway it is a solution - points moved randomly by 0.001 do not change anything really. But still interested why such situation occurs.